# add form data to grid view using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've to pass data from this form field to the `GridView` using `javascript`. I searched in internet but can not found any way of doing this using javascript.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" id="txtFamName" autocomplete="off" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Age</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" runat="server" id="txtFamAge" autocomplete="off" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="SUBMIT" OnClientClick="btnSubmit_Click()"/>
</div></div>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"
    runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    Width="100%"
    HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
    CssClass="gridview"
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="even">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S No." ItemStyle-Width="10%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField
            HeaderText="NAME">
            <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField
            HeaderText="AGE">
            <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top" />
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: a gridview is just a HTML table by the time it gets to your browser, so maybe search for how to append items to a HTML table using Javascript. If you then need to persist the values to the server, that's another piece of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the data that is going into the `GridView` in a `DataTable` in session, and then every time you click the button, add a row to the `DataTable` and rebind the `GridView`.

You need to set the `BoundField` DataField property to the column name that you are using in your `DataTable`.

If you want me to show you how, I can update this with an example code.

**EDIT:**

You'll need to set the DataField property to the column you want to bind, so change your markup to:

```
<asp:BoundField
    HeaderText="NAME"
    DataField="Name">
    <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top" />
</asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField
    HeaderText="AGE"
    DataField="Age">
    <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Top" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

In your `Page_Load` event, you will need to create the DataTable and store it in session for later use.

```
protected void Page_Load() {
    // Create a new table and store in session.
    DataTable d = new DataTable();
    d.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name"));
    d.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Age"));
    Session["myData"] = d;
}
```

Finally, on your button click, you will want to add a new row to the DataTable and bind it to the GridView.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click() {
    // Get our data table from session.
    DataTable table = (DataTable)Session["myData"];

    // Create a new row.
    DataRow dr = table.NewRow();

    // Add to the row the values of the text boxes.
    dr["Name"] = txtFamName.Value;
    dr["Age"] = txtFamAge.Value;

    // Save the row to the table.
    table.Rows.Add(dr);

    // Rebind the gridview and save it back in session.
    GridView1.DataSource = table;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    Session["myData"] = table;
}
```

I hope this helps.